# Show that these have a common root

Tags: polynomials

> Show that these
>
> $ax^2 + (b + d)x + c = 0$
>
> $bx^2 + (c + d)x + a = 0$
>
> $cx^2 + (a + d)x + b = 0$
>
> have a common root if and only if $a+b+c+d = 0$
> $a<b<c<d$ and non-zero

It is quite clear that when $x=1$, the root is confirmed. However, adding all equations is not giving something useful. Is there some method to solve such questions?

Moreover, can a solution using determinants be possible?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: The "if-and-only-if" statement means that whatever proof is provided, it needs to work both ways

Comment: The question still remains...

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h421070p2378205

Comment: @MartinR Perfect

Comment: @mathx The "*only if*" part requires the additional assumption that $a,b,c$ are not all equal.

Comment: @dxiv Let $a>b>c>d$

Comment: @mathx You should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4159217/edit) that into the question, not as a comment. The condition is stronger than needed, the only other solution is $a=b=c$ (when the three equations become identical).